# How does eq? in Racket work?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

At my university we had to work with Racket and since I kind of liked it, I bought the recently published book "Realm Of Racket" from No Starch.

It's great so far, however, I cannot figure out what they mean in Chapter 4 when they try to explain how *eq?* works:

1. At first, they explain how *equal?* compares whether two values consist of identical pieces. OK, no problem, I got that: *equal?* does pretty much the same thing as Java's *equals(someObject)* method. If two objects/structs/whatever are the same contentwise, #t is being returned.
2. Then, I figured, *eq?* must be the equivalent to Java's *==* operator, which doesn't compare contentwise but based on references.
3. This thought seemed to be confirmed by the following sentence in the book: *"eq? compares whether changing one structure changes the other structure..."* Great! Let's compare it to the following piece of Java code:

   ```
   Point p1 = new Point(5, 5);
   Point p2 = p1;
   System.out.println(p1 == p2);   // true, since the reference has been copied.
   System.out.println(p1.x);       // 5
   System.out.println(p2.x);       // 5
   p1.x = 42;
   System.out.println(p1.x);       // 42
   System.out.println(p2.x);       // Accordingly, 42
   ```

   Let's try this in Racket:

   ```
   (define cons1 (cons 1 empty))
   (define cons2 cons1)
   (eq? cons1 cons2)           ;; #t, since the refernce has been copied.
   (set! cons1 (cons 2 empty))
   cons1                       ;; Returns '(2) - as expected.
   cons2                       ;; Still returns '(1).
   ```

   Why? cons2 points to cons1, which itself points to '(2). Additionally, didn't they just say that they are equal as soon as one changes the other?

Obviously, right now I don't get why this doesn't behave as expected and because of that, I don't see what *eq?* is doing. Maybe I am wrong and it does not have anything to do with references...

If someone knows about this, please share your wisdom ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a technical explanation of how `eq?` works, take a look at the current [specification](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.5), you won't find a more detailed reference. Or simply check Racket's [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html) on the subject, in particular the procedures `eq?`, `eqv?` and `equal?`. Regarding your question - the result is as expected and correct in the Scheme code, let's see why. Notice that in this line in Java:

```
p1.x = 42;
```

You're modifying the *same* object that's being pointed at by both `p1` and `p2`. Whereas in this line:

```
(set! cons1 (cons 2 empty))
```

You're creating a *new*, different object and setting `cons1` to point to it, but `cons2` is still pointing to the old object. You can confirm this, after the previous line, the comparison `(eq? cons1 cons2)` will return `#f`.

The point is: the examples are not equivalent. The Java example deals with a single object that's being pointed at by two different references, whereas the Scheme example deals with two objects and two references.

For comparison purposes, here's a Scheme example that's similar to the Java code, and works as you expected because in here we're modifying a single mutable object that's being pointed at by two references:

```
#lang racket
(require scheme/mpair) ;; `m` stands for "mutable"

(define p1 (mlist 5 5))
(define p2 p1)

(eq? p1 p2)       ;; #t
(mcar p1)         ;;  5
(mcar p2)         ;;  5

(set-mcar! p1 42)
(eq? p1 p2)       ;; #t
(mcar p1)         ;; 42
(mcar p2)         ;; 42
```

Answer (score 4):

Ah: you want to make sure you're changing structure.  In your example, it is actually not changing the structure of an existing value, but rather constructing a whole new value and directing `cons1` to it.  You have the concept right: `eq?` is pretty much Java's `==`.

Just to analogize, here's the mistake in Java form just so you see what went wrong:

```
int[] lst1 = new int[] { 1 };       // (define cons1 (cons 1 empty))
int[] lst2 = lst1;                  // (define cons2 cons1)
System.out.println(lst1 == lst2);   // (eq? cons1 cons2)
lst1 = new int[] { 2 };             // (set! cons1 (cons 2 empty))
System.out.println(lst1[0]);        // (list-ref cons1 0)
System.out.println(lst2[0]);        // (list-ref cons2 0)
```

In fact, at this point, you'll want to check for `eq?`-ness at the end of this: you'll see that the two are no longer `eq?`: they're two distinct values.

What you really want is to do **mutation** on the structure, rather than a variable rebinding.  In Racket, since lists are immutable, you'll want to use a different data structure that allows for mutation.  *Vectors* are one example datatype that can demonstrate.  Let's "Rosetta" this up again so you see the analogy:

```
(define vec1 (vector 1))          ;; int[] vec1 = new int[] { 1 };
(define vec2 vec1)                ;; int[] vec2 = vec1;
(eq? vec1 vec2)                   ;; System.out.println(vec1 == vec2);
(vector-set! vec1 0 2)            ;; vec1[0] = 2;
(vector-ref vec1 0)               ;; System.out.println(vec1[0]);
(vector-ref vec2 0)               ;; System.out.println(vec2[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, that `eq?` compares references to determine equality. This is much more efficient than `equal?`, which must recursively compare objects.

The [Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html) documentation explicitly defines each, as well as the related `eqv?` function:

> **equal?**
>
> Two values are equal? if and only if they are eqv?, unless otherwise specified for a particular datatype.
>
> Datatypes with further specification of equal? include strings, byte strings, pairs, mutable pairs, vectors, boxes, hash tables, and inspectable structures. In the last six cases, equality is recursively defined; if both v1 and v2 contain reference cycles, they are equal when the infinite unfoldings of the values would be equal.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> > (equal? 'yes 'yes)
> #t
> > (equal? 'yes 'no)
> #f
> > (equal? (expt 2 100) (expt 2 100))
> #t
> > (equal? 2 2.0)
> #f
> > (equal? (make-string 3 #\z) (make-string 3 #\z))
> #t
> ```

---

> **eqv?**
>
> Two values are eqv? if and only if they are eq?, unless otherwise specified for a particular datatype.
>
> The number and character datatypes are the only ones for which eqv? differs from eq?.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> > (eqv? 'yes 'yes)
> #t
> > (eqv? 'yes 'no)
> #f
> > (eqv? (expt 2 100) (expt 2 100))
> #t
> > (eqv? 2 2.0)
> #f
> > (eqv? (integer->char 955) (integer->char 955))
> #t
> > (eqv? (make-string 3 #\z) (make-string 3 #\z))
> #f
> ```

---

> **eq?**
>
> Return #t if v1 and v2 refer to the same object, #f otherwise.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> > (eq? 'yes 'yes)
> #t
> > (eq? 'yes 'no)
> #f
> > (let ([v (mcons 1 2)]) (eq? v v))
> #t
> > (eq? (mcons 1 2) (mcons 1 2))
> #f
> > (eq? (make-string 3 #\z) (make-string 3 #\z))
> #f
> ```

Comment: The `eq?` parts must be what is garanteed to be `eq?`. There are much more that are `eq?` in reality but probably not garanteed to be in the future, like: `(eq? (+ 4 5) (+ 5 4)) ==> #t`, `(eq? 5e100 5e100) ==> #t`, `(eq? "racketeer" "racketeer") ==> #t`. see http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._model-eq%29